# Flutter network not connecting to FirebaseAuth services

Tags: swift, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

so I have been working on this **Flutter** app that simply needs to log into firebase authentication with an email and a password through `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword()`. Whenever I do, it throws this error:

Android Studio Error:

> [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/network-request-failed] Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

XCode Error:

> 2022-05-28 22:31:47.393894+0400 Runner[53493:5966626] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]

Here is my **Dart** code for the section (not sure if more is required):

```
try {
   final credential =  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text,        //emailController is a text field controller
        password: passwordController.text   //passwordController is a text field controller
      );
    } 

   on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
     if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
     } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
     } else if (e.code.isEmpty){
        print('worked!');
     } else{
        print(e.code);
     }
   }
 }
```

My XCode app delegate:

```
import Flutter
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    FirebaseApp.initialize()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Google Services info file is included in the project.

If there's anything else missing, please tell me. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: did you get answer?

Comment: Sadly not. I've tried everything and now I've just resorted to a local server database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue because I was running an Android app on an emulator, so I added the line of code below. and after running the app on a real device using the same code, I started having problems.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator("localhost", 9099);
```

**Remove above line if you are running app in real device**

Answer (score 1):

Please check your firebase firestore rules. Go to your firebase console -> Your project -> Firestore -> Rules and change from `if false:` to `if true:`.

This might be the reason firebase is refusing to connect.

Make sure your app is properly configured by following the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Not sure if this is useful but I don't even use Firestore. I'm just using the Firebase Authentication service. 

Nonetheless, I have set up Firestore with the correct permissions and it has still broken. 

In reference to the android project setup, I am just using the XCode runner and so I don't think that the android files are ever touched or complied.